# Scraping Data from Metadata in Python

Tags: python, json

I need to get data from the following statement:

```
{"info":{"symbol":"NIFTY","companyName":"NIFTY","identifier":"none","activeSeries":[],"debtSeries":[],"isFNOSec":true,"isCASec":false,"isSLBSec":false,"isDebtSec":false,"isSuspended":false},"filter":{"expiryDate":"Invalid date","strikePrice":""},"underlyingValue":11655.25,"vfq":7501,"fut_timestamp":"28-Aug-2020 15:29:23","opt_timestamp":"28-Aug-2020 15:29:25","stocks":[{"metadata":{"instrumentType":"Index Options","expiryDate":"03-Sep-2020","optionType":"Call","strikePrice":11700,"identifier":"OPTIDXNIFTY03-09-2020CE11700.00","openPrice":50,"highPrice":85.4,"lowPrice":42.75,"closePrice":0,"prevClose":43.1,"lastPrice":66.9,"change":23.800000000000004,"pChange":55.220417633410676,"numberOfContractsTraded":507931,"totalTurnover":23603.55},"underlyingValue":11655.25,"volumeFreezeQuantity":7501,"marketDeptOrderBook":{"totalBuyQuantity":514575,"totalSellQuantity":236475,"bid":[{"price":66.85,"quantity":75},{"price":66.8,"quantity":75},{"price":66.6,"quantity":1425},{"price":66.55,"quantity":900},{"price":66.5,"quantity":1875}],"ask":[{"price":66.9,"quantity":225},{"price":66.95,"quantity":375},{"price":67,"quantity":2100},{"price":67.05,"quantity":1950},{"price":67.1,"quantity":975}],"carryOfCost":{"price":{"bestBuy":66.85,"bestSell":66.9,"lastPrice":66.9},"carry":{"bestBuy":-31396.45257775595,"bestSell":-31391.904290939718,"lastPrice":-31391.904290939718}},
```

Comment: It seems like a json data, just load it using the json module and it will convert it into a key value pair which can be easily parsed.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there looks like JSON data.

Consider the following:

```
parsed = json.loads("INSERT JSON DATA HERE")
```

Alternatively, if you store the JSON data in a file, you can use the following:

```
import json
with open('jsonDataFile.json', 'r') as data:
    parsed = json.load(data)
```

Here is a good resource to help you understand JSON data and how to use it in Python: [Using JSON in Python](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/json-python-parsing-simple-guide/#:~:text=Parsing%20JSON%20Using%20a%20Custom%20Class.%20By%20default%2C,specifying%20an%20object_hook%20function%20which%20handles%20the%20conversion.)

Comment: how can get the metadata date part in dataframe format in python? also its is from the json api url